# how to inflate data from database in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

i just set my listview empty..but now after adding data into database from another activity,and tried to show that data in list view ,it giving the same emptyview..it is not showing the data,how to retrieve data in listview..??

Campaign.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Campaign_Details extends Activity  {

    private Demo selectedAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_demostration);
        TextView text1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        DataBaseHandler info= new DataBaseHandler(this);
        info.open();
        String data=info.getData();
        info.close();
        String[] values= new String[]{ data };      
        //txt.setText(data);
       // Button next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
      //  Map<String, String[]> storage = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
     //   String[] tableItems = storage.get("ContactTable");


       // next.setOnClickListener(this);
    // final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

         ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
         ListView listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

         listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
        // TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        // listview .setEmptyView(emptyText);


      final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            selectedAdapter = new Demo(this,values);
            selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);


            listview.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
            list.add(values[i]);
       }

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
              int position, long id) {
              Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SmsSend.class);
            startActivity(n);

          }
        });
         }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nextPage:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,SmsSend.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

demo.java //custom adapter

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Demo extends ArrayAdapter{
    private Campaign_Details list1;
        // used to keep selected position in ListView
       private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected
        private Context context;
        private String[] values;

        public Demo(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }



        public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
             // inform the view of this change
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public int getSelectedPosition(){
             return selectedPos;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 View v = convertView;
                        LayoutInflater vi =   (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

                 // get text view
                     TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.data);

                    if (convertView == null) {            
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
                    }
                    else
                        v = convertView;
                    TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data);
                    text1.setText(values[position]); 
                    return v;
                }
        }
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DataBaseHandler{

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="person_name";
    public static final String KEY_SCALE="scale_person";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Scaledb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private DbHelper ourHepler;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                    );
            }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DataBaseHandler(Context c){
        ourContext=c;
    }


    public DataBaseHandler open() throws SQLException{
        ourHepler = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase=  ourHepler.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        ourHepler.close();
    }


    public long entryCreate(String name, String scale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SCALE, scale);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv); 

    }


    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE};
        Cursor c=  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
        String run="";
        int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iScale=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALE);

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            run=run+c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + "\n";
        }

        return run;
    }


    public String getScale(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String scale=c.getString(2);
            return scale;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String getName(long l)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name=c.getString(1);
            return name;

        }
        return null;
    }


    public  void updateEntry(long lt, String mName, String mScale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ContentValues cvUpdate=new ContentValues();   
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,mName);
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_SCALE,mScale);
          ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE,  cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "-" + lt, null);
    }


    public void deleteEntry(long ltt) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + ltt,null);

    }


    public void getWritableDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

activity_list_demonstration.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Active Campaign"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#4AE56B" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Tab on Icon to start a Campaign" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Closed Campaign"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="No Closed Campaign" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your String[] Data not empty.

Second your database return one long string and not String array and will get only one row in ListView

```
for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        run=run+c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + "\n";
    }
```

also you get only last row or empty row

change it to something like this

```
List<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
           dataArray.add(run+c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + "\n");
        }
    return dataArray;
```

set your adapter to use List array;

public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<String> dataArray;

public SampleAdapter(Context context,List<String> dataArray){
    this.context = context;
    this.dataArray = dataArray;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView txt1;      
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row_item_layout,parent, false);
        viewHolder  = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txt1.setText(dataArray.get(position));


    return convertView;
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SampleAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("data line 1");
    array.add("data line 2");
    array.add("data line 3");
    array.add("data line 4");
    array.add("data line 5");


    adapter = new SampleAdapter(this,array);
    ListView listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);




}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

fix this first

```
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {

    list.add(values[i]);
}
selectedAdapter = new Demo(this,values);
listview.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
```

also your adapter need this method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.length();
}
```

Comment: what exactly not work can you provide more information error/exeptions

Comment: there is no error application is running but data is not visible in list